# Round Up/down with Rule Using Math Function only?

Tags: c#, .net, math

Some Math people please help, I want to convert using only Math. Function. (Pow, Floor......etc) with only single statement  as possile, not using if else to check if the 5fifth digits after decimals from 1-4 or 6-9 .

- i want to convert 5 digits after decimal to 5 digits after decimal with the following rules , alway 5 and 0 at the end.

## Rule 1:

```
double number1 = 1.2345* 
if( * from 1 to 4)
   number1 ==> 1.23455 
if ( * from 6 to 9)
  number1  ==> 1.23460
```

## Rule 2:

```
double number2 = 1.2345* 
if( * from 1 to 4)
   number2 ==> 1.23450 

if ( * from 6 to 9)
  number2  ==> 1.23455
```

I Came up with answer for Rule 1, but it need to 2 statement, I wonder if it can be done with only 1 statement

```
number1 = Math.Floor((number1 + 0.00005) * 20000) / 20000 - 0.00005;
number1 = Math.Floor((number1 + 0.00005) * 20000) / 20000 ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Might this be homeworkz?

Comment: no, this is rules i want to add to my code, to convert stock rate as the rules define above

Comment: In your description for Rule 2, you have for digit 6 through 9 that it should go to 1.23465, which would be rounding up plus adding. Do you instead mean 1.23455?

Comment: If you care about the decimal representation of a number, then `double` is almost always the wrong choice. Use `Decimal` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For rule #1:**

```
var y = (int)((x - 0.00001) * 20000) / 20000.0 + 0.00005;
```

Result:

```
1.23450 => 1.23450
1.23451 => 1.23455
1.23452 => 1.23455
1.23453 => 1.23455
1.23454 => 1.23455
1.23455 => 1.23455
1.23456 => 1.23460
1.23457 => 1.23460
1.23458 => 1.23460
1.23459 => 1.23460
1.23460 => 1.23460
```

**For rule #2:**

```
var y = (int)(x * 20000) / 20000.0;
```

Result:

```
1.23450 => 1.23450
1.23451 => 1.23450
1.23452 => 1.23450
1.23453 => 1.23450
1.23454 => 1.23450
1.23455 => 1.23455
1.23456 => 1.23455
1.23457 => 1.23455
1.23458 => 1.23455
1.23459 => 1.23455
```

Comment: rule 2, round down instead of round up

Answer (score 2):

Remember how you round (to an integer):

```
round (a) = floor (a + .5)
```

So, now salt it with some multiplications with powers of 10, some adding of .5 and pepper it with some division by powers of 10 and you are set.